# Cannot import name pyplot

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

matplotlib import error. Python 2.7 32 bit running on windows 10. I have tried pip uninstall matplotlib and reinstalling, but same error keeps cropping up.

I have tried all variations of the import command.
Please help!

code:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.show()
```

error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Anand/PycharmProjects/test1/matplotlib.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anand/PycharmProjects/test1/matplotlib.py", line 2, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Anand\PycharmProjects\test1\matplotlib.py", line 2, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ImportError: cannot import name pyplot
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: post your relevant line of import code and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this import line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```